# PHP PDO connection failure throws warning and script execution times out

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to instantiate a PDO object like this:

```
$this->pdo['pdo'] = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF-8',
                    'myuser', 'my pass');
```

I'd like to catch the exception that I thought would be thrown when the MySQL server is not running.

PHP.net says "PDO::__construct() throws a PDOException if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails."

But if I shut down the database server and run the script all I get is a warning:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] 'A connection attempt failed 
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.' in
C:\test\test.php on line 5

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\test\test.php 
on line 0
```

No exception is thrown.

Is there a direct way of catching the error (without the hassle of temporary setting a custom error manager function?)

Thanks!

Comment: execution time exceeded is a fatal error that can't be trapped. If it could be, people could trivially bypass the time limitation and run scripts as long as they wanted, just by putting the "important" bits into the error handler.

Comment: I just found the solution:

`$this->pdo['pdo'] = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF-8', 'myuser', 'my pass', array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10"));`

The last parameter (the attributes array) allows me to specify a timeout shorter than PHP's max execution time.  Then the exception throws OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the array config as 4th param of PDO():

```
PDO::setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT , '5' );  //> Secs
```

To lower the connection timeout

and

```
PDO::setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

to always throws Exception.

Usage:

```
new PDO(,array(

              PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10",
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION         

));
```

Comment: So, the instantiation should be:  
 `$this->pdo['pdo'] = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF-8', 'myuser', 'my pass', array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10")); `

Comment: @sebastian: nope :). that was taken from offical docu as example

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I finaly solved it.

The thing is, I had a "new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb','myuser', 'my pass');" into a for/while loop.

When I do 3 or 4 loops it is all right. When I have 5000 iterations, my mySQL server seems to block me and then I get the "Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] 'A connection attempt fail..." error message.

I know this wasn't too clever to put a "new PDO(..." into a loop. Hope this will help you guys.

antoine

Comment: That's more a workaround than a solution, but thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I think that the problem was either the php engine or the mysql's one had an hard time openning 500 conections almost simultaneously. Since I made all the query with the same user on the same DB, I had no need for openning new connections. I think that issue is related with overload of the mysql server or maybe a protection against too many request by the same source at a time. Well, I don't much except it solved my issue. :)